# Small modal doesn't appear small

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So i saw that link : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts.
And wanted to add the small modal on my project.
I copied the same code from the link but instead of showing small, it's bigger ! With no header and cross button ! 
What am i missing ?

[image]

This is the code :

```
<!-- Small modal -->
    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I did tried to use an header like on the others examples above , but not working (at least for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bootstrap site, they have included the minimum code, that's why you cannot find the header which is included in:

```
<div class="modal-header"></div>
```

As for the small modal box, your code should work correct *if* you have this in your CSS:

```
.modal-sm{width:300px}
```

Check out the **[demo](http://www.bootply.com/133417)** made.